# form.is_valid() always returning False in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Below is my code for Form submission .when i submit the form form,is_valid always returning false not sure want went wrong with my code. I am just started learning Django any help is highly appreciated  TIA

HTML

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">

      <form method="post" class="form-signin" action="/loginvalidation/">{% csrf_token %}
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
          </label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Html file

```
view.py

def loginvalidation(request):
    print request
    form = LoginssForm(request.POST or None)
    print form.is_valid()
    if form.is_valid():
        save_it=form.save(commit=False)
        print save_it.email
        save_it.save()
        user = authenticate(username='john', password='secret')
        if user is not None:
    # the password verified for the user
            if user.is_active:
                print("User is valid, active and authenticated")
            else:
                print("The password is valid, but the account has been disabled!")
        else:
    # the authentication system was unable to verify the username and password
            print("The username and password were incorrect.")
    return render(request,"about-us.html",locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))]
```

View. py for my code

```
Model.py

class LogIn(models.Model):
    email=models.EmailField(null=False,blank=False)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=1201,null=True,blank=True)
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
    updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=True)
```

Model of application
 Model of applicationModel of application

```
    form.py

    class LogInForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model=LogIn
            fields = '__all__'
```

Above is my code for Form submission. When I submit the form, form.is_valid always returns False. I just started learning Django any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you print `form.errors`, it will tell you the errors in the form. However, I strongly recommend that you don't try to create your own authentication system in Django. It is much more secure to use the included [authentication that comes with Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/).

Comment: Printing form.errors got this  but i am sending value of password from form     <ul class="errorlist"><li>password<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>email<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>

Answer (score 3):

It appears you're missing a "name" attribute on your fields in the HTML file, thus the value is never actually getting posted to Django. If just add `name="email"` and `name="password"`, respectively, to the fields, then the values should get passed through and begin properly validating.

However, that being said, I agree with Alasdair's comment above. It would be far more secure and recommended to use Django's built in authentication system.

Comment: It's a test project i am learning on it, i will use the djnago auth only. Even adding name="email" and name="password" still not working

Comment: @user1844634 What do you mean *"i will use the django auth only..."*? This has got nothing to do with Django. You'll need to set the `name` attributes on form inputs so that the data is sent to the server. Do you know HTML?